# Check whether OleDb 12.0 driver for MS Access is installed or not

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a C# application which uses OleDb 12.0 driver to connect to an MS Access database. If the OleDb 12.0 driver is not installed, the application throws an exception which is not relevantly explanatory.

```
public static class Program
{
    private static Mutex mutex = null;
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            InMemoryValues.CorrectnessRepetition = 15;
            InMemoryValues.MultipleChoiceCount = 6;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }

        ... ...
        ... ...

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();  
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);  
        Application.Run(new CollectionForm());  
    }  
}
```

I want to let users know about the specific problem of not having a driver. I don't want to hard-code the information.

How should I do that?

**Relevant Source Code**

```
public static class InMemoryValues
{
    private static ApplicationData _appData = null;
    public static int CorrectnessRepetition { get; set; }
    public static int MultipleChoiceCount { get; set; }

    static InMemoryValues()
    {
        _appData = ApplicationDataBLLL.Get();

        if (_appData == null)
        {
            _appData = new ApplicationData();
        }
    }

    public static ApplicationData ApplicationData
    {
        set 
        {
            _appData = value;
        }
        get 
        {

            return _appData;
        }
    }

    public static void Save()
    {
        ApplicationDataBLLL.Save(_appData);
    }
}
```

Comment: how about catching the especific expection and replacing with you own message or logic ?

Answer (score 3):

Using [`OleDbEnumerator.GetElements()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbenumerator.getelements?view=netframework-4.8&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) you can get a `DataTable` which contains list of all visible OLE DB providers.
The first column of the returned data table, is `SOURCES_NAME` which is the invariant name of the native OLEDB data source or enumerator.

So you can use the following code to find out if `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` is installed and visible to the executing process:

```
var oledb12Installed = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbEnumerator()
    .GetElements().AsEnumerable()
    .Any(x => x.Field<string>("SOURCES_NAME") ==
        "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0");
```

**Bitness**

Keep in mind, if you are compiling the application for X86 while you have installed X64 versions of the `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`, then above code will return false which means your application cannot use `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`.

You need to use the package with the same bitness as your application. You can download the provider from the following link:

- [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)

After clicking on Download button, you have the choice to download x86 or x64.